# Meta-regression analysis of the correlation between dependent variables

Tags: r, meta-analysis, biostatistics, meta-regression, metafor

I have a set of studies which report a biomarker and an incidence of an outcome at baseline and at end of follow-up. I would like to get a measure of how much the change in the biomarker(chg_bm) influence the incidence rate ratio(IRR). As I understand the problem I want to use a dependent variable (chg_bm) which has its own variation as an independent variable in a meta-regression setting with IRR being the dependent variable while still properly taking study effects into account.
I am looking for a good description on how to handle this kind of problem and code for the actual analysis.

Currently I have 2 strategies:

1. Treat the change in biomarker as not varying and then use it as a mediator for the meta analysis of the IRR where IRR is modelled using a  binomial normal model (see section 3.4 of Stijnen 2010). This seems obviously incorrect but was a first attempt.
2. Do a bivariate analysis treating both the change in biomarker and IRR as dependent variables. This is fitted using a random effect model and an unstructured covariance matrix. Afterwards the regression between the change in biomarker is found from the fitted covariance matrix using
   $ b = R_{chg, chg}^{-1}*R_{chg, IRR} $ where $R$ is the $2\times2$ covariance matrix. This is essentially done following the example [here.](https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses:vanhouwelingen2002#regression_of_true_log_odds). I am not entirely sure what is going on here. Furthermore, I only know how to do the actual code for the analysis using Gaussian families (no glm) which seems incorrect.

Safe to say that the 2 methods does not give the same result (for one thing method 1 is on a log scale while the other is not).

EDIT: The last code snippet seems to render differently between the editor and the final post. I don't know how to fix that (and also seems odd).

**Data and code examples:**

| study | chg_bm | chg_bm_sd | n_evnt_in | obs_in | n_evnt_fin | obs_fin | IRR | IRR_sd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1.36 | 1.61 | 111 | 26.94 | 9 | 39.13 | 0.06 | 0.02 |
| B | 0.60 | 1.17 | 4 | 0.47 | 3 | 0.4 | 0.94 | 0.72 |
| C | 1.30 | 0.92 | 4 | 0.54 | 3 | 0.63 | 0.51 | 0.39 |

In total I have 17 studies. The number of events and observation time for the baseline and follow-up periods where used for the IRR and IRR_sd calculations.

1.

```r
    res <- df_irr %>% metafor::rma.glmm(measure="IRR", 
             x1i=n_evnt_fin , t1i=obs_fin , x2i=n_evnt_in , 
             t2i=obs_in, mods = ~ chg_bm , data = ., 
             model="CM.EL")
```

2. 

```r
    df_irr_long <- rbind(
     df_irr %>% select(study, chg_bm, chg_bm_sd) %>% mutate(yi = 
          chg_bm, vi = chg_bm_sd^2, group = "bm"), 
          df_irr %>% select(study, IRR, IRR_sd) %>% mutate(yi = 
          IRR, vi = IRR_sd^2, group = "irr")
    )
    res <- rma.mv(yi, vi, mods = ~ group - 1, random = ~ group | 
              study, struct="UN", data=df_irr_long , 
              method="REML")
    reg <- matreg(y=2, x=1, R=res$G, cov=TRUE, means=coef(res), 
              n=res$g.levels.comb.k)
```

---

Stijnen 2010: Random effects meta-analysis of event outcome in the framework of the generalized linear mixed model with applications in sparse data. See also [here.](https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses:stijnen2010)